# Applying Table cell borders

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with the class "productsTable". I want to give each cell in the table a border. Now I have tried the following in my stylesheet but none of the two works. What am I doing wrong? Thank You

```
td.productsTable
{
    border: 1px dotted #999999;
}

.productsTable td
{
    border: 1px dotted #999999;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="productsTable" width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="2px;">
<tr>
<td width="40%">We Offer:</td>
<td class="ephoneFree tableHeader" width="20%" align="center">e-phone FREE</td>
<td class="personal tableHeader" width="20%" align="center">Personal</td>
<td class="PBX tableHeader" width="20%" align="center">Pro PBX</td>
</tr>           
<tr>
<td width="40%">Pricing</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">FREE</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">£3 per month</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">From £5 per month</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show me your html code also for that table

Comment: All else being equal, both of those will work… providing the markup you have matches the selectors you are writing. If it doesn't work then either your markup doesn't match or you have other styles overriding these. Since we can see neither, we can't say which.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`td.productsTable` **won't work** because you have no `<td>` elements with a `productsTable` class.

However, your second CSS rule, `.productsTable td`, this **will work** because you do have `<td>` elements that have a parent element with the class `productsTable`.

I've made a quick fiddle of this, and you can see it working correctly:

```css
td {
  border: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="2px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">We Offer:</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">e-phone FREE</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">Personal</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">Pro PBX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Pricing</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">FREE</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">£3 per month</td>
    <td width="20%" align="center">From £5 per month</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If this isn't working for you, its likely that you have either not correctly linked your CSS file, or there is another CSS rule overriding this. Try [inspecting element](http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/) to see.

Comment: thanks, it works. Appreciate your help...I think the file just took a long time to reach the server maybe...really wasting my time issues like this.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to give each cell in the table a border.

What I've understand is you want cell border like this:

[image: table]

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95y95/1/)** of what you want.

***Use following CSS:***

```
table.productsTable {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: gray;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color: white;
}

table.productsTable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: ;
}
```

​
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

write like this:

```
.products td
{
    border: 1px dotted #999999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="products">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But that will jsut effect all of the td's, that's not what he wanted.

Comment: I am agree with you but he didn't show his HTML structure So, it's hard to understand how his html structure.

Comment: If a question can't be reasonably answered, don't answer it.

Comment: @Quentin if you saw the question you get some idea which say what OP did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below code does the following:-
1. gives single border to td's
2. separate border to the table.

Environment:-
Works on FF 34.0.

Untried for html6:- 
To run it using html6, try it with html:x eg. html:head, html:title, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    </script>
    <title>Welcome to the jungle</title>
    <style>
.table_main {
        border-top-style: ridge;
        border-bottom-style: ridge;
        border-left-style: ridge;
        border-right-style: ridge;
        border-color: red;
        border-width: 3px;
      }

.table_main td {
    background: #A38055;    
    border-right: solid 1px white ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

.table_main th {
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border-right: solid 1px white ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the jungle</h1>
    <table class="table_main" width="400" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <thead>       <th>THead1</th> <th>THead2</th> <th>THead3</th>
     </thead> 
      <tbody>
        <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>X</td> <td>Y</td> <td>Z</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>Xena</td> <td>Yoda</td> <td>Zohan</td> </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```